# Running into an Angular nested form error in unit test, what is the error?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

So I am getting the following error in unit testing a nested angular form:

```
 No value accessor for form control with path: 'address -> address1'

      at _throwError (../packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts:140:9)
      at setUpControl (../packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts:37:27)
      at FormGroupDirective.addControl (../packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive.ts:132:5)
      at FormControlName._setUpControl (../packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts:278:66)
      at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (../packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts:207:28)
```

The form is defined as follows

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    address: this.fb.group({
      address1: '',
      address2: '',
      ...
    })
  })
}
```

Template:

```
<form formGroup="form">
        <form formGroupName="address">
          <custom-text-input formGroupName="adress1" label="Address 1">
          </custom-text-input>
          <custom-text-input formGroupName="adress2" label="Address 1">
          </custom-text-input>
          <custom-text-input formGroupName="phone" label="Phone">
          </custom-text-input>
          <custom-text-input formGroupName="zipCode" label="Zip Code">
          </custom-text-input >
          <custom-text-input formGroupName="state" label="State">
          </custom-text-input >
        </form>
      </form>
```

Comment: Show us the template file.

Comment: added, custom text input has the CtonrolValueAccessor implemented.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing an additional `this.fb.group({})` when nesting form controls

```js
this.form = this.fb.group({
   address: this.fb.group({
      address1: [''],
      address2: ['']
   })
})
```

Have a read from the official docs on [Reactive Forms - Generating form controls](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-3-generating-form-controls)

---

Also, `formControlName` only works with `<input>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>`. Do double check your template file if you had used `formControlName` on any other elements.

If you wish to use `formControlName` with another form control, you will have to create a custom form control using `ControlValueAccessor` class. See this alligator.io's article on [creating custom form controls](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/).

---

**EDIT**

Aside from `formGroupName` input binding, there's also `formControlName` input binding that's used for controls declared inside a FormGroup.

Taken from Angular's official docs, [Associating the FormGroup model and view](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-3-generating-form-controls):

> The formControlName input provided by the FormControlName directive binds each individual input to the form control defined in FormGroup. The form controls communicate with their respective elements. They also communicate changes to the form group instance, which provides the source of truth for the model value.

```js
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    address: this.fb.group({
      address1: '',
      address2: '',
      ...
    })
  })

//is equal to

   this.form = new FormGroup({
      address: new FormGroup({
          address1: new FormControl(''),
          address2: new FormControl('') 
      })
   })
```

As you can see, address1 and address2 is not a new instance of form group. I think your code should work if you use `formControlName` instead of `formGroupName`.

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <form formGroupName="address">
        <custom-text-input formControlName="adress1" label="Address 1">
        </custom-text-input>
        <custom-text-input formControlName="adress2" label="Address 1">
        </custom-text-input>
        <custom-text-input formControlName="phone" label="Phone">
        </custom-text-input>
        <custom-text-input formControlName="zipCode" label="Zip Code">
        </custom-text-input>
        <custom-text-input formControlName="state" label="State">
        </custom-text-input>
    </form>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, that I'm already doing, to be clear the component is working fine, its just for unit test thats failing.

Comment: could you edit in your test suite, or at least the test case that's failing along with your beforeEach, afterEach, etc?

Comment: hi @user2167582, I have edited my answer, I think the structure of your form is still wrong, that's why it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found was adding the custom component to the declarations array when configuring the TestBed module.

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ CustomFormControlComponent],
      imports: [ FormsModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        CommonModule, ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });
```